# Route Groups in NextJs throws error, doesn't opt out of app layout.tsx

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

afaik, the layout.tsx in the app directory is the root layout
and in order to opt out of this layout structure, one can use Route Groups
[source](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/defining-routes#example-opting-specific-segments-into-a-layout)

wherein (directory_name) containing layout.tsx will be followed for any page.tsx inside this directory

layout.tsx (app directory)

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import './globals.css'

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <nav className='navbar'>
          <h1><Link href={'/'}>Home</Link></h1>
          <h1><Link href={'/wikirocket'}>WikiRocket</Link></h1>
          <h3><Link href={'/about'}>About</Link></h3>
          <h3><Link href={'/users'}>Users</Link></h3>
        </nav>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

layout.tsx (inside (wikirocket) directory)

```
import Navbar from './wikirocket/components/Navbar'

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({children}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className='bg-slate-800 text-cyan-200'>
        <Navbar />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

thus when i run *http://localhost:3000/wikirocket*
i should not see the navbar displayed through the app layout
but i still see it displayed for a brief second and immediately followed by the following errors:

[image: list of errors]

removing the html tag from the wikirocket directory layout.tsx only gets rid of one error which specifies the problem

i just dont want to see the navbar from the app layout.tsx and let the layout.tsx inside (wikirocket) directory override the prev one

Comment: Like the error says _It is an error to render more than one body component at a time_ it looks like the layout from the wikirocket is getting rendered inside the layout of the app. See [Next.js Nesting Layouts](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/pages-and-layouts#nesting-layouts) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The layout of nextjs works in a way that the other layouts occurs as a child of rootlayout, so the html and body tags cannot appear as a child of html or body. So first, you need to remove the html and body tags from wikirocket directory layout.tsx and just wrap like that

```
import Navbar from './wikirocket/components/Navbar'

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({children}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
       <section>
        <Navbar />
        {children}
        </section>
  )
}
```

and it is not possible that the layout of any directory overrides the rootlayout.